# Simplifying TryGetValue to access an attribute of the key's value?

Tags: c#, dictionary

Is there any way to do this, such as using lambdas in some fashion?  If I have a Dictionary, is it possible to shorten my code so that TryGetValue puts out Foo.a instead of just returning the object?

Right now it feels a bit long-winded, with eg "a" as int:

```
int a;
Foo bar;
if(!dict.TryGetValue(key, out valueObj)) {
    a = 0;
}
else {
    a = bar.a;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why you need LINQ to achieve something so simple?

```
public Object GetObjectFromDict(string foo)
{
    if (someDict.ContainsKey(foo))
    {
        return someDict[foo];
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Um yeah, this was one of those instances of falling down a rabbit hole and losing touch with the basics.  Thanks for the slap in the face!

Answer (score 4):

You can slightly simplify this with a conditional expression and the new C#'s `out var` feature:

```
int a = dict.TryGetValue(key, out var valueObj) ? valueObj.a : 0;
```

This is essentially the same solution as you presented, only rewritten on a single line.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a one liner:

```
int a = dict.TryGetValue(key, out SomeClass valueObj) ? valueObj.a : 0;
```